# SPI clock signal problem

Tags: interconnect

I am working on a breaboard prototype involving an Arduino; it used to work fine (connection point (a)) until last day when SCK went missing. Or not missing but distorted; sometimes the logic analyzer would not catch it at all. As a result I always read back zero via SPI (probably written garbage as well).

**The setup**:

- ADC part soldered to an adapter PCB (the green one)
- which further connects to a copper breadboard through some thick pins (sacrificed paperclips)
- which connects to a strip of standard 100 mil female connectors through some soldered wires on the breadboard
- which further connects to Arduino pins through some wires

The problematic thick pin is pictured as a red wire running from it to its 100 mil standard female connector.

[image]

**Problem**

The only way I can get my SPI communication up again is by firmly pressing a female wire against the thick pin in spot (b). Doing the same but in spot (c) does not work. The fix is temporary; as soon as I move the contraption around SCK connectivity goes flaky again.

**Tried**

- changing SCK wire between the black connector and the Arduino
- continuity test with my DMM on all the SCK track

Why am I seeing this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't solder properly to a bit of paperclip wire, so now you have a bad connection. Pressing against that poor connection allows it to work temporarily. Remove the paperclip wires and replace them with copper wire.